# como ocultar div si no tiene contenido con css o js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola comunidad una consulta como podría hacer para ocultar un

```
<div></div>
```

si este no tiene contenido y mostrarlo cuando si hay contenido?.
Quiza sea facil la pregunta pero no se aun mucho de programación gracias.

Comment: Usando solo CSS:  `div:empty {display:none;}` Ten en cuenta que si el `div` tiene al menos un espacio en blanco si se mostrará. Más detalles en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:empty).

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Esta genial! Ponlo como respuesta, es la mejor sin duda.

Comment: @masterguru gracias, ahí agregué una respuesta.

Answer (score 7):

Puedes ocultar los `div` vacíos usando solo `css` mediante la pseudo-clase [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:empty), para ello establece en tus estilos:

```
div:empty {
  display:none;
}
```

Este selector matcheará todos los `div` que estén vacíos y los ocultará. Te adjunto un ejemplo **SIN** el selector y otro **CON** el selector para que se aprecie la diferencia.

### Sin `:empty`

```css
div{
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div>s</div>
<div></div>
<div>m</div>
<div></div>
```

### Con `:empty`

```css
div{
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
}

div:empty {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div>s</div>
<div></div>
<div>m</div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Muy bien explicado tambien!  Gracias por el aporte

Answer (score 3):

Con este código en javascript ocultas todos los vacios, y en el caso que alguno reciba contenido dinámicamente debes analizar cuando eso se puede producir y cambiarle la propiedad `display` por la que desees en ese momento.

```
divs = document.querySelectorAll('div')
divs.forEach(elem => {
  if (elem.textContent == ""){
    elem.style.display = "none"; 
  }
})
```

donde:

- `divs = document.querySelectorAll('div')` recoge en la variable divs todos los elementos `div` de tu documento gracias a la función [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- `divs.forEach(elem => {` inicia un bucle [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) donde recorrerlos todos, y donde `elem` representa a cada uno de ellos dentro del bucle en cada ciclo.
- `if (elem.textContent == ""){` realiza una comparación del contenido del div (que conocemos gracias a la propiedad [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)) con una cadena vacía, y si se cumple entra en el condicional para aplicar el ocultamiento
- `elem.style.display = "none";` realiza el ocultamiendo aplicando la propiedad de CSS `display:none` sobre el elemento que ha conseguido entrar en el condicional.

Answer (score 1):

Poniendo una id al div y escondiendo o enseñando segun si tiene contenido o no.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>

    <script>

contenido = document.getElementById('content');

  if (contenido == ""){
    contenido.style.display ='none';
  }else{
    contenido.style.display ='initial';
  }

</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No era `.style.display = 'none'`?

Comment: Funciona de las dos maneras.

Comment: No estoy tan seguro.. en jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/2c5nkwy3/) me dice que no: `TypeError: contenido.style.display is not a function"`

Comment: Yo lo probe con visual studio y el navegador y si me funciona, lo voy a editar, si que es verdad que la forma corracta correcta es la tuya, me confundi, pero aun asi funciona, por eso no me di cuenta..

Comment: No, no funciona, lo que ocurre es que igualmente en tu navegador no se aprecia nada, porque no hay ningun contenido, pero si te vas a la consola veras esto: `Uncaught TypeError: contenido.style.display is not a function` (probado en firefox y chrome), y si inspeccionas el codigo veras qeu no se agrega el style que pretendes aplicar.  Por otra parte, usas `contenido == ""`  cuando diria que esto también está mal, porque no le dices que propiedad debe ser la que no tenga contenido, se lo estas preguntando a todo el elemento en si

Comment: Vale, ahora ya has arreglado una cosa, pero si inspeccionas el HTML con el inspector (boton derecho sobre la página, opción Inspeccionar) verás que le pone el style **initial** porque como decia usas **contenido** como si fuera una de las propiedades que gestiona su contenido, cuando es todo el elemento en si.